# counting radio buttons not working with multiple tag names

Tags: java, selenium

[image]    File file = new File("D:\Selenium 2.48\IEDriverServer.exe");

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.yatra.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        List<WebElement> radio = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
        System.out.println(radio.size());
```

**here is the new code, and i am able to lacate xpath now .thanks for it.But issue is with a white page which comes and result is zero .The original page takes some time.**

[please find the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiQOP.png)

i wanted to count the number of radio buttons.
but i was not able to . I tried finding it by tag name and the result is zero.
The HTML is bit complicated to my understanding as in radio buttons , there is no input .hence i cannot find by `input[@type=]` etc

Please help me in this regard .[image]

Comment: The input type for radio boxes in html is <input type = ''radio'' name="gender" value="male"> maybe you can use that..

Comment: the issue is with IE only.In chrome its working.Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should locate the right indicator for these ratios

Recommend you to use this xpath

```
//a[@data-flighttrip]
```

Here's my script

```
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class TestSelenium {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "res/chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

        driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

        driver.get("http://www.yatra.com/");

        List<WebElement> radio = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@data-flighttrip]"));
        System.out.println(radio.size());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Here's console output

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.9.248315) on port 14427
3
```

Tried with IEDriver

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class TestSelenium {
    static WebDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("D:\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
        DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);

        WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);

        driver.get("http://www.yatra.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        List<WebElement> radio = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@data-flighttrip]"));
        System.out.println(radio.size());

        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Result

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.52.0.0
Listening on port 6267
Only local connections are allowed
3
```

Comment: your code partially for me.Now  i am able to identify element by the xpath. now. But when i try with IE result is zero as first page is blank and then it goes to the given uRL.

Comment: I've just given a try with IEDRiver and it works normally. I'm using IE11 with IEDriverServer_x64_2.52.0

Comment: glad it could help you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to wait for things to settle down and the page to load via [`WebDriverWait`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.trip-type")));
```

Here, we are waiting for the trip type container *to become visible*, which, I assume, is a good indication that at least the relevant part of the page is loaded.

Then, you can count the links:

```
List<WebElement> radio = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
System.out.println(radio.size());
```

---

Note that the radiobuttons are not actually HTML radio input elements in your case - these are just links with preceding "radiobutton"-like icons:

```
<a class="type-active" href="javascript:void(0);" data-flighttrip="O"> 
    <i class="sprite-booking-engine ico-be-radio">&nbsp;</i>
    One Way 
</a>
```

So, if you want to count these types of links anywhere on the page, you may check for the presence of the `i` child element with a `ico-be-radio` class with the following XPath expression:

```
List<WebElement> radio = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(i/@class, 'ico-be-radio')]")); 
System.out.println(radio.size());
```

But, if you want to just check how many "trip type" links are there, just get all of the `a` elements inside the "trip type" container:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 10);
WebElement tripType = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.trip-type")));

List<WebElement> radio = tripType.findElements(By.tagName("a")); 
System.out.println(radio.size());
```

Comment: Hi , yes i guess issue is with wait , as i get white page first and then 0 is printed in console even before original page laods. So tried your code ,but new exception is there.